# Assume $A$ is positive-definite and $S$ is skew-symmetric. $A,S\in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$. Prove $|A+S|\gt 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $A$ is positive-definite and $S$ is skew-symmetric. $A,S\in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$.  Prove
$$|A+S|\gt 0$$

I was doing it in this way. For any non-zero vector, $x^TSx=0$, hence $x^T(A+S)x \gt0 $. And I want to conclude $A+S$ is positive-definite and hence it's determinant greater than $0$. But finally I figured out $A+S$ is not even  symmetric. So  I can't conclude $A+S$ is positive-definite. And don't know how to do it right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of positive-definiteness or symmetry, the inequality
$$x^\top(A + S)x > 0$$
implies that $\operatorname{det}(A + S) > 0$. Why? Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A + S$. If $\lambda$ is real, then for some $v \neq 0$, we have
$$0 < v^\top (A + S)v = v^\top \lambda v = \lambda\|v\|^2,$$
hence $\lambda > 0$. Note that, in particular, we cannot have $\lambda = 0$.

Otherwise, $\lambda$ is non-real, which means $\overline{\lambda}$ is also an eigenvalue with equal multiplicity. Multiplying these eigenvalues together yields $|\lambda|^2$, which is a strictly positive number, as $\lambda \neq 0$.

Therefore, in computing the determinant, we multiply only strictly positive numbers: positive real eigenvalues and square moduli of the complex eigenvalues, hence the determinant is strictly positive.